# Angular date filter not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Controller**

```
app.controller("MarketController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.dates = [
        { date: Date.parse("01/01/1999"), value: 123.456 },
        { date: Date.parse("02/05/2004"), value: 789.123 }
    ];
});
```

**Template**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in dates">
    <span>{{item.date | date: 'EEE'}}</span>
</li>
```

The date value doesn't work with the filter, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Angular? Any errors in your console?

Comment: @Phil 1.4.5 - no errors

Comment: Instead of `Date.parse`, try `new Date('01/01/1999')`, etc

Comment: It does work - https://jsfiddle.net/w76gd930/2/ What is the rest of the code? Show the full HTML.

Comment: Do you see anything if you type {{item.value}} in another span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works actually:

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller("MarketController", function($scope) {
  $scope.dates = [{
    date: Date.parse("01/01/1999"),
    value: 123.456
  }, {
    date: Date.parse("02/05/2004"),
    value: 789.123
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='MarketController'>
  <li ng-repeat="item in dates">
    <span>{{item.date | date: 'EEE'}} - {{ item.value }}</span>
  </li>
</div>
```

Probably you misspelled `ng-repeat`?

Comment: The only difference is that we are using Angular as a local resource from nuget, rather than from a CDN

Answer (score 0):

Try this for date filtering:

```
$filter('date')(date, 'yyyy.dd.MM');
```

Do not forget to inject the `$filter` in this line:

```
..['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter){...}
```

Comment: Why isn't Angular's built in date filtering working?